# Creating a trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger on a table after inserting, which gonna update another table.

this is the code I tried :

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER augmenter_quantite_article AFTER INSERT
ON LigneInterventaire
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE @qte AS INTEGER;
DECLARE @code AS INTEGER;
SELECT @qte = qteInv FROM INSERTED;
SELECT @code = codeArt FROM INSERTED;
UPDATE Article SET qteArt = qteArt + @qte WHERE codeArt = @code;
END;

|

delimiter ;
```

but I get this error message :

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@qte AS INTEGER; DECLARE @code AS INTEGER; SELECT @qte = qteInv
>   FROM INSERTED; S' at line 4

Comment: I think you need to SELECT **INTO** within stored procedures or triggers. You can't just have a select hanging by itself. Also, double check whether you have to use `:=` instead of `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
CREATE TRIGGER augmenter_quantite_article 
AFTER INSERT ON LigneInterventaire
FOR EACH ROW 
  UPDATE Article 
     SET qteArt = qteArt + NEW.qteInv
   WHERE codeArt = NEW.codeArt;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2af312/1)** demo.

MySql has somewhat limited trigger implementation.  There are no virtual tables `inserted` and `deleted` per se as in SQL Server. Instead you can access old and new values of a row that is being inserted or updated with keywords `OLD` and `NEW` respectively.

Since it boiled down to only one `UPDATE` statement you no longer need to use `BEGIN END` block. Another plus - you don't need change `DELIMITER` either ;)

Comment: What the `New` stands for ?

Comment: It's an analog for `inserted` but only for one row that is being inserted. That's why it reads `FOR EACH ROW ...`